# Make table in R Markdown using tabular() and booktabs

Tags: r, r-markdown, tabular, tables-package

I am using the `tabular()` function in the `tables` package to make tables in an R Markdown file.  I would like to use the `booktabs()` option to include a horizontal rule.  However, when I do so, the code from `booktabs()` appears in my LaTex document, even when I set the chuck option to `echo=FALSE`.

How can I use the `booktabs()` option with `tabular`?

Output: 
[image: tables with booktabs output]

And here is the code for the example:

````
---
title: "Making Tables"
output:
  pdf_document: default
header-includes: \usepackage{booktabs}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(tables)
library(Hmisc)
```

```{r no line, results='asis'}
latex(tabular( (Species + 1) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*(Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)*(mean + sd), data = iris))
```

```{r with line, results='asis', echo = FALSE}
booktabs()
latex(tabular( (Species + 1) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*(Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)*(mean + sd), data = iris))
```
````

Comment: Would you be open to using kableExtra instead, or is there a technical reason you have chosen this route?

Comment: I liked the aesthetics of the tables package better, but if it's easy to do in kableExtra I would be open to it. It also seemed easier use with cross-tabulated data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `invisible` function around `booktabs` like this:

````
```{r with line, echo = FALSE,results= "asis"}
invisible(booktabs())
latex(tabular( (Species + 1) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*(Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)*(mean + sd), data = iris))
```
````